# What does "A mod P generates the residue class field extension" mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

We have K and finite algebraic extension L.

P is a prime ideal in $O_{L}$ over prime $p\in O_{K}$ and $A\in O_{L}$.

Then the problem says $\bar{A}:=A ~mod ~P$ generates the residue class field extension $(O_{L}/P)/(O_{K}/p)$. Does that mean the power basis of $\bar{A}$?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to say definitely without seeing all the text, but my first guess would, indeed, be that you get the field $\ell=O_L/P$ from the usual copy of $k=O_K/p$ inside $\ell$ by adjoining the coset $\overline{A}=A+P$ to it. As everything in sight is finite, this means that the powers of $\overline{A}$ span $\ell$ as a vector space over $k$.

Comment: @Jyrki Here is the context. I shortened it to get more replies. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761203/if-phia-pi-then-o-k-o-ka?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $l/k$ is any field extension we say $l$ is generated over $k$ by $\alpha$ if $l=k(\alpha)$. So "generated by" is a field notion here. You're probably thinking of the linear algebra notion of "spanned by." Indeed, the claim $l/k$ is generated by $\alpha$ is equivalent to the powers $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\cdots\}$ spanning $l$ over $k$.